# Horizontal scroller in CSS

Tags: css

I have been trying to add a scroller to my context section that will only allow the box to scroll horizontally within the visible of the viewer's screen, not vertical.

Does anyone know any code to have scrollable content in a div in a fluid css layout design?

Also, here is a link to a website that has the exact scroll effect I am trying to recreate: http://patrickhoelck.com/home.html

Comment: The site you've linked to is using an IFrame to embed another web page within his home page. He's not doing it with CSS. overflow-x will do what you want in CSS.

Comment: In my code, a horizontal scroller appears in the correct location, but it does not have a scroll. Instead, the browswer allows me to scroll the entire layout instead of the single content section.

Comment: Have you set a fixed width on the parent of your content (eg the containing div)?

Comment: I attempted to add in a fixed with to my div, but there was no effect. Here is the code I am currently using: <div style="width:auto;height:375px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal !important;">

Comment: Added some working HTML to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [overflow-x: scroll](http://www.blooberry.com/~bloo/indexdot/css/properties/position/overflowx.htm), which, along with setting a fixed size on the parent, will force a horizontal scrollbar if the content is too wide.

Some example html:

```
<div style="width: 50px; overflow-x: scroll">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
    <p>Here is a div with a horizontal scrollbar!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly. Thank you! I have been having trouble with this for weeks.

Answer (score 12):

> Does anyone know any code to have scrollable content in a div in a fluid css layout design?

'overflow: auto' will add the scroll bar when necessary.

The trick is to make sure the content inside the scrollable element exceeds the normal width of the element, instead of simply reflowing onto a new row in which case it'll never trigger a scroll bar. One way to do this is by using 'white-space: nowrap'.