# How to float unordered list in a fixed-width overflow div

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal scroller in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449241/horizontal-scroller-in-css)

I have a 320px wide `DIV`. There's a `UL` `LI` navigation inside, where each `LI` is floated left to display them in a single line. I want them to stack next to each other and display a scrollbar at the bottom of the parent `DIV` to scroll the content horizontally.

- I don't know the number of `LI`s (dynamically generated)
- I don't know the width of `UL` (dynamically generated)
- *Multiple* items have to be visible at once, not just one at a time!
- I'd like to use CSS-only method to solve this.

  ```
   #menu
   {
      width: 320px;
      overflow: scroll;
   }

   ul li
   {
      float: left;
      display: block;
   }

   <div id="menu">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Car</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Very long text item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Foobar foobar</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  ```

Problem: it doesn't work. No horizontal scrollbar. Floats wrap and stack in multiple lines in the parent DIV.

Comment: Are you attempting a horizontal scrolling gallery type of thing..? Where you can only see one <li> at a time inside the #menu div?

Comment: No, it's not a gallery, it's a navigation, multiple items have to be visible at any given time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to float the `<ul>` left as well, and give it a crazy big negative margin to ensure it's width always surpasses that of the outer DIV. Like so:

```
#menu
{
  width: 320px;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: -30000px;
}

ul li
{
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

​
The `float: left` on the UL ensures you don't have all that extra white space made by the giant margin.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8SEQT/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..
Assign the width of each `<li>` ..

```
li
{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-right:-110px
}
```

The `margin-right:-xxxpx` will always leave some xxxpx space after each item to accommodate another item into it and thus prevent the list item from going to next line...

Comment: Thanks, but I can't assign a width to LIs, each one contains a text of a different length, the width has to be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a horizontal scroll is if the UL is wider than #menu.

Since you don't know how many elements you will have, you could set your UL element to a randomly high width e.g.  `ul {width:9000px;}` to keep all your floating LI elements in one row.

Also, i would set your #menu to overflow:auto rather than overflow:scroll.

Answer (score 0):

try this. You could even count the width of the each li and add that to a var then set that to the width of the menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/jxA3d/

/**UPDATE**/

I've updated it to be completely dynamic.

Comment: Looking for a CSS-only solution

Comment: @MusikAnimal Please remove the javascript tag then. you can still use my jfiddle just don't use the javascript and add a width to the #menu